# ContentProvider: filter incoming requests

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My project contains 2 providers: `BannerProvider`, `ItemProvider`. When I request ItemProvider with:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Contract.Items.CONTENT_URI,null, null);
```

my BannerProvider gets triggered. Is it the expected behavior or there're means to direct those requests to corresponding providers i.e. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Ok, I figured it out - I used to have `android:authorities=.data.provider.BannerProvider` and `android:authorities=.data.provider.ItemProvider`. After I added additional path parameter: `android:authorities=.data.provider.banner`, `android:authorities=.data.provider.item` it began to route requests as expected. Thanks to Luksprog

Comment: I doubt that happens assuming that you didn't mess up the uris.

Comment: +1 @Luksprog i think there should be 2 different URIs for Banner and Item